# bash script / standard_in 1: syntax error

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I am running a bash script on ubuntu and on the command line I get this error repeating for a couple of times while the script is running:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: N
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: U
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: L
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: L
```

Can anyone give me a clear explanation to understand the meaning of this?

Comment: Please post the script.

Comment: Also, how are you running the script? It appears you are piping commands to a shell with something like `echo ... | bash`, since the script itself has no name.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is:

You did not follow the syntax rules of one in your script enclosed commands.
(this is the absolute maximum answer you can get based on your input )